# Adding phone number into existing contact

Tags: android

How can I add a phone number into existing contact in my contactlist programmatically?  I know how to add or delete contact, but i cannt add phone number into one of the contacts... So, help me please.

Comment: What code have you tested?

Answer (score 3):

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
//...
//add Phone to existiong Contact
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId)
    .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, delta.getAsString(Phone.NUMBER))
    .withValue(Phone.TYPE, delta.getAsString(Phone.TYPE)).build());
//...
//add Email to existiong Contact
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId)
    .withValue(Email.ADDRESS, delta.getAsString(Email.ADDRESS))
    .withValue(Email.TYPE, delta.getAsString(Email.TYPE)).build());
//...
try {
    mContext.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    Log.d(TAG, "update success");
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "update failed");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`rawContactId` is the `android.provider.ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID`

you can query with `Contacts.CONTENT_URI` to get this

`delta` is `RawContactDelta`, you can replace `delta.getAsString(Phone.NUMBER)`, `delta.getAsString(Email.ADDRESS)` with any String value

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Example.

```
try {
     ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withSelection(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + "=? AND " +
         Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
         new String[]{contact_id})
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, "anything")
        .build());

     ContentProviderResult[] result = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```